# Unknown Property Error in NPSP

Tags: apex, visualforce, error

I keep hitting a snag when trying to "manage households" in NPSP. I get error:

Unknown property `$ObjectType.Account.fields.npe01__One2OneContact__r`

Error is in expression

> `{!$ObjectType[sObjType].fields[field].dependentPicklist}` in component `<apex:variable>` in component `npsp:util_formfield`
>
> Error evaluating dynamic reference `npe01__One2OneContact__r.npe01__HomeEmail__c`

I ran both npe01 Apex tests and both passed. Any help would be greatly appreciated... As a fairly new admin, I'm just not sure what the move is!

Comment: Do you have FLS to the fields `Account.npe01__One2OneContact__c` and `Contact.npe01__HomeEmail__c`?

Comment: hmmm I'm not even seeing fields with those names in FLS or in the fields/relationships lists.

Comment: Their labels will certainly be different than the API names, but they should be there.

Comment: Figured it out. I had made changes in field sets and although I'm not sure precisely the issue, reverting back to the default sets solved the issue.